# Need to catch the onTap Event has occured or not In Android

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay

I need to catch the onTap event.Although i have onTap function but it opens my overlay if i tap once and close the overlay if i tap twice... I need to catch when this onTap has happened... How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

override the method `"onTap()"` where you extended the class `"ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>"`

Comment: Hey Vineet,how to detect whether the onTap Is already pressed or not?